# Select last item in <select> list using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `<select>` element on my form with the multiple attribute set to "true".  After the element gets populated, how can I select the last item in the list using jquery? I want the item to be selected the same way you select it with a mouseclick:

[image]

Comment: @Nivas: Your first duplicate link seems right, but definitely not the second one. You should have just voted to close with your first link.

Comment: @BoltClock Agreed - the second one is not related. I did not intend to post that. Need more coffee. (I already did flag to close and now deleted the second comment)

Comment: I don't really understand what you need, but here my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/kfLf7/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try

```
    var myVal = $('.someclass option:last').val();
    $('.someclass').val(myVal);
```

where someclass is the select class or it's wrapper element class.

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/8tBYa/1/)

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by index value as well:

```
var num = $('select option').length;
$('select').prop('selectedIndex', num-1); // For choosing last item in list
```

Comment: This answer was better for me in my case because of duplicate values (fringe case)